# Use macro to define print format arguments

Tags: c++

I want to define the format `%lld` and use intro `printf` or `snprintf`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>

using Custom_DataType = int64_t;
#define CUSTOM_FORMAT "%lld"

int main()
{
    Custom_DataType  var = 9999999999;
    printf("It works", CUSTOM_FORMAT, var);

    return 0;
```

}

I want to do something like

```
printf("It works %lld", var);
```

I want to replace the `%lld` with `CUSTOM_FORMAT`
But if i do it like my above example don't work

Comment: `std::cout << "It works " << var` will work for any built in type without having to specify the type.

Comment: @NathanOliver std::cout can do some formatting with iomanip but printf even if not typesafe has some advantages, when it comes to formatting. however I thing boost provides something that fills the gap

Comment: Note that you are still mixing abstractions by assuming that `int64_t` is the same as `long long`. If it was, we wouldn't need both. To be on the safe side you would have to use a format macro like `PRId64` from [<cinttypes>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string literal concatenation. Since

```
"STRING1" "STRING2"
```

is equivalent to

```
"STRING1STRING2"
```

You can write:

```
#define CUSTOM_FORMAT "%lld"
printf("It works " CUSTOM_FORMAT, var); // <-- no comma ;)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("It works", CUSTOM_FORMAT, var);
```

That comma `,` makes no sense. Get rid of it:

```
printf("It works " CUSTOM_FORMAT, var);
```

---

Then again, since you're using C++ why don't you use `std::cout`.